# Möbius-transformation $w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I'm struggling a bit with the Möbius transformation below.

Describe the image of the region under the transformation

b) the quadrant $x>0, y>0$ under $w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

My solution is so far:

1. Check that it is in fact a valid M.transformation with $ad-bc \neq 0$.
2. Calculate transformation of 3 points on the edge of quadrant, using points in a specific order:

$p_1=(i)$ $\Rightarrow w(p_1)=0$

$p_2=(0)$ $\Rightarrow w(p_2)=-1$

$p_3=(1)$ $\Rightarrow w(p_3)=-i$

At this point, i assumed it would be enough with 3 points, but when looking at the image i get and the answer it does not make sense how to end up with the answer.

Would anyone like to give me hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Possible approach: It maps $y>0$ to the open unit disk. If you can find the image of $x>0$ you can take the intersection of the two.

Comment: Another hint: calculate $w(k \cdot i)$ for $k \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$. Then you will probably see that the boundary $\{x=0\}$ is mapped to a specific line segment. As $w(1)=-i$ you will then know where $\{x>0\}$ is mapped to (namely the side of the line that $-i$ lies in).

Comment: Mobius transforms map circles and lines to circles and lines. If the transform maps any point on a line/circle to $\infty$, then the image of that line/circle under the transform is a line (a circle that goes through infinity). I find this kind of geometric heuristic helpful, maybe you will too. Of course, a formal proof will be easier to do algebraically, as the answers demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hints,  check that $f(2i)=1/3$.  Putting that together with  $f(0)=-1, f(i)=0$, we see that the imaginary axis goes to the $x$-axis.  Since $f(1)=-i$, the right half plane goes to the lower half plane.

But it's easy to see,  and well-known,  that the upper half plane goes to the unit disk.

Finally,  the intersection of the unit disk and the lower half plane is the lower half disk.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (too long for a comment)

Rearrange to make $z$ the subject and write $w=u+iv$

You can apply the conditions $Re(z)>0$ and $Im(z)>0$ to obtain inequalities in terms of $u$ and $v$